# 3D Array indexing in NumPy to reduce number of rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array with the shape:

```
data = (5433L, 3543L, 3L)
```

I want to make new array by subtracting 100 rows from the end:

```
ans = (5433L-100L, 3543L, 3L)
```

How to do it?

Comment: what about `data[0:-100,:,:]` ?

Comment: Which 100 rows do you want to subtract? From the end?

Comment: @ajcr yes rows from the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing to stop 100 rows before the end of the array:

```
ans = data[:-100]
```

With this notation NumPy slices just the first dimension of `data`: other dimensions are left intact (i.e. it's equivalent to `data[:-100, :, :]`).

**Note**: `ans` still shares the same underlying memory as `data`: any changes made to one array will be seen in the other. If you want `ans` to be a brand new array in memory, you need to explicitly make a copy:

```
ans = data[:-100].copy()
```